# Why does Intent implement Cloneable?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, clone

Why does Android's `Intent` implement `Cloneable`? Are Intents ever cloned?

Intent's [`clone()` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.clone%28%29) is broken as it invokes the constructor instead of calling `super.clone()`. Subclasses of Intent are guaranteed to have broken behavior if ever cloned (corresponding [Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=173608)).

Comment: Not if the subclasses override `clone()` and do the same thing: Call their own copy constructor. --- I'd say `clone()` is *flawed* by not changing return type to `Intent`, forcing a caller to cast, bypassing Java type safety.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care about `clone()`, do you ever use this (not for intents, but at all)? It's kind of broken in java (http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html), I always use a copy constructor instead.

Also, as far as I can remember you can not really extend `Intent`. If you do this and try to start an `Activity` or a `Service` with this object you will get an `android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling`.

So, I don't think you should worry about `clone()`, especially for `Intent`s.